# Edit Media - Edit Custom Sized Featured Images

Tags: post-thumbnails

When I edit images in the wordpress backend - crop, aspect ratio etc. my featured images don't change. I've tried all combinations of saving (All image sizes, Thumbnail, All sizes except thumbnail). How can I make these changes effect my featured image?

This featured image is a custom size using add_image_size()

eg. `add_image_size( 'featured', 638, 300, true );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be down to how the featured image is being called as it's possible to pass an array with a custom size, rather than using one of the set image sizes that comes with WP, or indeed a new image size that was added with `add_image_size()` - what code are you using?

Comment: Yes it is a custom size, how do I get these to be edited in edit media?

Comment: I don't think you can (but not 100% sure). You'd need to update the image size in your add_image_size function and re-upload or regenerate the image(s) using a plugin.

Comment: I've tried regenerating thumbnails after making the edits - that did not work.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Yes, is this something you have been able to do before?

Comment: Well, I've changed my mind on an image size before and had to re-create them all. Have you checked what sizes are now in the wp-uploads folder? How are you calling the featured image in your theme?

Comment: I'm adding the featured image like this: <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured'); ?> Surely it must be possible to edit these images?

Comment: Can I see this running anywhere online?

Comment: Unfortunately I am running it on a local install. I'm assuming I must be doing something wrong thanks for your help though.